# LocalTransportSender not found when using web services

Tags: java, web-services

I am not a big fan of web services, but sometimes you have to conform with a client interface.  I have successfully generated code from the the provided WSDLs, but when I try and run the application which actually uses the generated classes, I get the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender
```

I am keeping the generated code in a separate project and have the following dependencies in my pom:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As stated, the jar gets generated without any issues, but when it is includes in the application that makes use of it, I get the said exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really see how your problem is related to web services. To me it looks more like a missing dependency in the Maven repository. The LocalTransportSender class should be in the axis2-transport-local artifact. Does axis2-kernel have a proper dependency on it? If not, you might have to add it yourself.

Comment: same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333654/axis2-dependencies-for-a-simple-soap-rpc-encoding-call
let me know if you find out the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Adding below dependency would probably should solve this problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You may specify <scope>runtime</scope> Since it's normally not needed during compile phase

Answer (score 0):

Use next dependencies , and you should not have any problem

For api axis 2

- axis2-adb

For runtime

- axis2-transport-local
- Laxis2-transport-http