# Axis2 dependencies for a simple soap "rpc encoding" call

Tags: java, apache-axis

we need to access an obsolete soap webservice with "RPC Encoding" style.
unfortunately this is not supported by modern tools, such as JAX-WS,
so we need to use the Axis2 library.

I've created the stubs with the maven plugin, as in this example:
[Error when using XmlBeans generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518301/error-when-using-xmlbeans-generated-classes)

However, when I call the webservice, it complains about missing dependencies.
I can add the missing dependencies using a trial and error approach (every time that I get a ClassNotFoundException, I find out the jar and I add the dependency in the pom file), but that's not a very good idea.

I looked at the Axis2 documentation, but I didn't find information about the dependencies needed for a simple soap call.
How can I know what are the minimum set of dependencies that I need in my case?

Comment: duplicated: http://blog.mograbi.info/2010/12/getting-really-annoyed-with-axis2.html?showComment=1358241239586#c919898062449358584

Answer (score 0):

USE [MAVEN](http://maven.apache.org/) , that will automatically resolves your dependencies in optimized manner. add following to your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: this dependency is not enough. for instance, if I don't add the org.apache.axis2 axis2-transport-local dependency, I get a ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender

Comment: when you run `mvn install` maven will automatically downloads all the necessary dependencies needed for the axis2 runtime